# What makes the processor to know about unsigned and signed numbers?

Tags: unsigned, signed, twos-complement

If I talk about `2'complement`, the `MSB` is used as a sign bit. For example in 8 bit `2'complement` `signed` notation `01111111` is `+127` and and `11111111` is `-128`. But on the contrary `11111111` is `255` in `unsigned notation`. How does the processor know if the number is `signed` or `unsigned`? Is there any other bit used for this purpose? Compiler makes something?

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of 2's complement is that the bit operations for arithmetic operations are exactly equivalent to `unsigned`. So most likely, the processor doesn't give a monkeys.

The same cannot be said for 1's complement arithmetic (it requires, among other things, a *complementing subtractor*), or signed magnitude arithmetic.

Comment: Let's say I apply `Negation ~` Operator to `1111` which is `-1` what will be the answer? your Statement can be true for adition or subtraction probably as I understand.

Comment: If I am a processor, somebody give me a nubmer I would also Need to know whether it was `signed` or `unsigned`?

Comment: No. If you are a processor you don't care. You just perform your operations.

Comment: If you apply negation (two complement's negation) on `1111` the result is `0001`. You are interpreting it as "`-1` negated is `1`" the processor doesn't care about that.